# What kind of shoes are worn by very haredi jews?

Tags: clothing

I noticed that the shoes of very haredi Jews (Toldos Aharon, Satmar, among others, including some very religious mitnagdim) were different. Do you know what kind of shoes it is (the name of it, maybe the brand) ?

These shoes are black, they look old, like the shoes people wore 200 years ago. You can see the Satmar Rebbe wearing them in this picture : http://www.vosizneias.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/sa3ers.jpg. I think that when these very haredi jews wear black socks instead of white socks the shoes are different, can you confirm ?

Comment: This question appears to be about Jews, and not about Judaism.  That is [off-topic for this site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @YEZ, Not so sure. Most chasidim will tell you that levush is very much part of their Judaism. (And I say this as someone for whom clothing means very little religiously)

Comment: @Yitzchak That wasn't the question, was it?  If the question was "why do they wear..." we could talk.  "What brand of shoes do they wear" is not a Judaism question, anymore than "what color head coverings did they wear in the 1400's" would be.

Comment: They wear certain brands because of religious reasons. So basically yes, it is related to judaism.

Comment: @msh210 Why not tag [tag:chasidut-hasidism]?

Comment: @Shokhet "including some very religious mitnagdim"

Comment: @msh210 But isn't the question *also* about chasidim?

Comment: @Shokhet Isn't "Is it permitted to slaughter a _sh'lamim_ on _Shabas_?" also about _chasidim_?

Comment: @msh210 "Is it permitted to slaughter a sh'lamim on Shabas?" is about *every* kind of Jew. The OP specifically mentions chasidim....the fact that he *also* mentions another type means that he's *not* asking about a practice of the chasidim also? ( *besides the fact that it will be easier for people to find this question about the levush if it has that tag* )

Comment: @Shokhet shall we take this to Bam?

Comment: @msh210 Sure; I'm a little busy now, though....maybe tomorrow?

Comment: It would be wonderful if you could edit your question and say a bit about why they wear such shoes, i.e., the religious reasons that push them to do so, as mentioned in your first comment above

Answer (score 6):

[image: "Quarter Shoe"]
They are called "quarter shoes" or פערטל שיך*  in Yiddish. They are only worn with breeches and knee-socks (regardless of color). Many wear these shoes only on Shabbos. (Even if they wear breeches on weekdays, they may wear more regular shoes, e.g. "half shoes" הלבע שיך.*) They are therefore also known as "sabbatical shoes" שבת׳דיגע שיך.

The style still exists in Turkey (just as the [Kaftan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44075/3073) does), where it is known as *Yemeni*.

There are many brands, some cater exclusively to the *Charedi*. Even the well known Turkish "[Esse Shoes](http://myedeveloper.com/esseshoes/mens_shoes.html)" *[Esse Ayakkabi](http://www.esseayakkabi.com.tr/index.php?s=urunler&id=9)* has its American branch in [Monsey, NY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsey,_New_York).

Source: Personal practice.

---

<sup>* Not "half shoes" הלבע שיך, as suggested by Yitzchak. That is a type of [loafer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip-on_shoe), also common among the same populations, but considered slightly less extreme, and can be worn even with regular long pants.[image: "Half Shoe"]</sup>

Answer (score 2):

They are called "half shoes" or האלבע שיך in yiddish (sp?). They are part of standard chasidic "dress" clothing worn with the breeches and knee-socks, regardless of color.

Comment: Are they of a certain brand ?