# Golden kaftan + high beaver hat?

Tags: minhag, clothing, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Normally, those wearing a golden kaftan (with a shtreimel) for [shabbes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/demcl.jpg) and [simchos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBCuL.jpg), will wear a [flat beaver hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvAKW.png) on weekdays. Are there any of those who wear a [high beaver hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWgWA.png) instead?

Answer (score 1):

I know a fellow that wears a Golden Kaftan with a Shtreimal on Shabbos and wears a regular up hat during the week.

Comment: I know a fellow that wears a fedora with a long brim on Shabbat and Yom Tov and wears a John Deer cap for the rest of the week.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Shouldn't it have been a comment like rosenjcb?

Comment: @rosenjcb Interesting. I know someone who wears a wide-brimmed fedora on BOTH Shabbat AND during the rest of the week!!! :-)